# How do I write out my Foundry dataset as a .csv?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I want to take my input and match the same number of records per file on my output, i.e. 1 parquet file input = 1 csv file output.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output, Input


@transform(
    the_output=Output("my.awesome.output"),
    the_input=Input("my.awesome.input"),
)
def my_compute_function(the_input, the_output):

    the_output.write_dataframe(
        the_input.dataframe(),
        output_format="csv"
    )
```

If you want to control file sizing operations, you can use `repartition()` as needed to control the number of records per file (more detail over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996685/how-many-files-are-output-by-a-foundry-transform-in-various-combinations-of-repa))